# Drag from mysql with counting and limiting

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

Is it possible to create a drag from mysql and count the total number of rows, but only get 20 rows at a time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean with "drag", but yes you can use [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) to retrieve 20 rows while still counting the total number of rows matching your criteria:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table WHERE ... LIMIT 20;
```

Then call `FOUND_ROWS()` in another query to fetch the total number of rows matched:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Comment: It is waye close but i have to be the total rows in the table not the matchin criteria. And I'd like to see it in one query. drag = query* :)

Comment: Why not a separate `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` then?

Comment: I do not know about my web space has disconnected several things that reduce connection time just as they have done with keepalive. So therefore I would like to reduce connections and queries because mysql server is on an external adrasse.; I do not have experience optimizing MySQL queries. So what would be the best solution?

Comment: IMO, it's not a good practice to try to group totally different queries into one, for performance reasons. Either try to understand why your database connection is slow/unreliable, or move this database to the server where your web server is physically located, rather than trying to find ugly hacks :)

Comment: Yes :).
- Do you have any link to a guide that addresses only the optimizing mysql